# Windows Server 2003 with 2 network cards and wireless router, is it possible to configure connections via router to use the AD server

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

In a small after school ITC class (1 server, 15 student machines), We have a vigor2800 adsl modem/wireless router.  This has a Windows 2003 server connected to it which has 2 network cards, one to the router and internet and one for the internal network of student machines.

We now have some ibooks we'd like to hook into the domain (via wireless).  If I put them on the same/internal network as the student machines, it can see and join the AD domain.

If I connect them via the wireless to the router, they can see the server, but not join its domain.

I guess the windows server is blocking AD type traffic from what it sees as its internet connection.

I am not sure how best to proceed:

1. Change the router/server connection to be marked as "private" in RRAS which might mean it will trust any traffic from it - relying on the router's firewall for any security concerns....
2. Radically, reorganize the network so that all clients connect to the router and thus the AD server should be visible to all.
3. Get a wireless router thing added to the internal network and thus make the AD server visible.
4. Some other change to the AD server to allow the router connected devices to talk to the domain...

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Volunteer sys admin, with minimal AD knowledge :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would move the wireless device to the internal network.  Any other solution would allow internet users to connect to your domain which would generally be considered a Bad Thing.  Let the wireless users route out to the internet through the DC just like the wired users do.

Comment: Good point/idea!

Comment: ..but this means buying some kit :(  as we still need an adsl modem between the server and the internet connection...

Comment: It does Chris, and I work in education myself so I realise that budgets are tight. The fact is though that for the sake of the price of a new wireless router you'll save hours and hours of your sanity, and potentially lost classroom teaching time, trying to make an awkward configuration work, and your one wireless router setup will never be as good or as simple to understand and fix as the setup with two.

Comment: IMHO, it's a more-than-justifiable cost in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to route traffic through your server? Can you not simply put the Vigor 2800 straight onto your LAN? You can still use the server as a web proxy if you want to monitor or restrict web access. The 2800 has an effective firewall if you need to restrict access from your LAN to the Internet.

JR

Comment: thats what I am thinking... we don't use it as a proxy or filter traffic with it...